# Adding to a class

Tags: c#

Given the following class

```
public class Company
{   
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPermission> Permissions { get; set; }

}

public class ProductPermission
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

What is the best way of adding a product permission to an existing product given I know the product ID?

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to answer your question. Are you asking how to find the Product by ID? Where are the products stored? Are they in a Database? Are you using an ORM? What have you tried already?

Comment: There is no *best* way, only *the* one way available given how things are set up: find the product by searching `Products` one by one and add the permission. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean best way, best Object Oriented way or best CPU performance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have an `IEnumerable<Product>`, otherwise you could change the product directly.

You can use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`(throws exception on multiple) to get the correct product according to a given GUID. Then you can add a permission to the list:

```
Product p = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == givenID));
if(p != null)
{
    if(p.Permissions == null)
        p.Permissions = new List<ProductPermission>();
    p.Permissions.Add(new ProductPermission{ID = givenID, Name="PermissionName"});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Lists, there are no good way of doing quick lookups - you should switch to `Dictionary<Guid, Product>` for that.

```
var perm = new ProductPermission() { Id = ..., Name = ... };
var prod = company.Products.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == perm.Id);
if (prod != null)
    prod.Permissions.Add(perm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, maybe you're looking for something like `Find`?

```
var product = company.Products.Find(p => p.Id == productId);
if (product != null)
    product.Permissions.Add(permission)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i would do it. I don't know if it is the best though.

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public void AddPermission(ProductPermission permission)
    {
        if(Permissions == null)
        {
            Permissions = new List<ProductPermission>();
        }
        Permissions.Add(permission);
    }
}
```

Then i would just call

```
product.AddPermission(permission);
```

In the above solution you don't need to check for null List in every bit of code that you want to add the permission. You will have it only in one place...

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrentProduct.Permissions.Add(new ProductPermission() {GuidId=System.Guid.NewGuid(), Name="HeyMega"});
```

You can do that in one line!

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a Company object and a ProductPermission object

```
Company c = new Company();
ProductPermission permission = new ProductPermission();

Product p = c.Products.Find((p)=>p.Id == id);

if (p != default(Product))
  p.Permissions.Add(permission);
```